# Place image/figure beside text {Lyx}

Tags: graphics, lyx

Is it possible to place an image beside (right or left) my text in LyX ?
something like that :

[image]

(The screenshot is not mine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LyX 1.6 uses the `wrapfigure` package to produce circumfloated pictures. You can access it on the menu at `Insert > Float > Figure Wrap Float`

If you insert a picture at the beginning of a paragraph, wrapfigure places the picture below the first line of the paragraph. To avoid that, insert the following code into the Preamble (that you can edit by going to `Document > Preferences`)

```
 \setlength{\intextsep}{0cm plus1cm minus1cm}
```

You can find more information in LyX's Wiki: http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/PlacingPicturesBesideTheText

Comment: Good point. Answer edited.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

Insert > Floats > Floating wrapped figure (the fourth one in submenu).